# createBrowserHistory is not working. The redirects are updating the URL, but not rendering the component

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom, browser-history

I'm using React Router v5 with a custom history object and redirects aren't working properly. I'm using react-router-dom 5.x ("^5.2.0") and history 4.x ("4.10.1"). My redirects are updating the URL, but not rendering the component without reloading the page.

AppRouter.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Router, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import {createBrowserHistory} from "history";
import {paths} from "../configs/routerConfigs";
import Main from "../modules/Main";
import Blog from "../modules/Blog"
import Store from "../modules/Store"
import Gallery from "../modules/Gallery";

const history = createBrowserHistory();


const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path={paths.blog()}
          exact
        >
          <Blog/>
        </Route>
        <Route
          path={paths.store()}
          exact
        >
          <Store/>
        </Route>
        <Route
          path={paths.gallery()}
          exact
        >
          <Gallery/>
        </Route>
        <Route path={paths.main()} exact>
          <Main />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

this is the header from where I redirect to another link

index.tsx

```
const AppHeader: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header className="app-header">
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col span={6}>
            <div className="logo">
              <img src={Logo} alt={"cosmonet logo"}/>
              <span>Cosmonet</span>
            </div>
          </Col>
          <Col span={12}>
            <nav className={"nav"}>
              <Menu className="nav-list" mode="horizontal" >
                <Menu.Item key="1" className="nav-list-items"><Link to={paths.main()}>{"Main"}</Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="2" className="nav-list-items"><Link to={paths.blog()}>{"Blog"}</Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="3" className="nav-list-items"><Link to={paths.store()}>{"Store"}</Link></Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item key="4" className="nav-list-items"><Link to={paths.gallery()}>{"Gallery"}</Link></Menu.Item>
              </Menu>
            </nav>
          </Col>
          <Col span={6}>
            <Button text={"log out"}/>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Header>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default AppHeader;
```

I tried another versions of react-router-dom and history but none of them seems to work properly. I even tried to use forceRefresh: true but it doesn't work either :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where the `AppHeader` is rendered in relation to the `AppRouter`, and vice-versa, but you are using two routers when you need only one routing context for your entire app.

The issue is that any navigation actions by the links in the `AppHeader` will be handled by the `BrowserRouter` you've used there. The `Router` wrapping the routes isn't made aware of any changes, that is until you refresh the page and  it remounts and reads the URL path.

I suggest removing the `Router` & `history` from `AppRouter` ***and*** the `BrowserRouter` from `AppHeader`. Move the `Router` and custom `history` object higher up in the ReactTree to allow providing a routing context to the entire app.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import App from "./App";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

AppRouter

```
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={paths.blog()} exact>
        <Blog/>
      </Route>
      <Route path={paths.store()} exact>
        <Store/>
      </Route>
      <Route path={paths.gallery()} exact>
        <Gallery/>
      </Route>
      <Route path={paths.main()} exact>
        <Main />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

AppHeader

```
const AppHeader: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Header className="app-header">
      ...
    </Header>
  );
};
```